# case statement values to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have several hard coded case statements  `(case when ID in ('1','2', etc) then X)`. Is there a way to show it as a `table` where ID values 1, 2 correspond to description X?

And then make a reference table.

Else I need to manual insert those values to that table. So eventually, I want to use a join with that table in my query rather than the case statement.

Comment: Use a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql).

Comment: Yes you can create table with columns id,description and use case statement to insert rows into second column

Comment: My thought is if there is any 'smart' way of achieving that. If I have to add all the Id by hand or write/alter a lot, then there isn't any reason the avoid manual insert all the values

Answer (score 2):

You can create a reference table within a query as:

```
with ref as (
      select v.id, v.val
      from (values ('1', 'x'),
                   ('2', 'x'),
                   . . .
           ) v(id, val)
     )
select . . .
from t join
     ref
     on t.id = ref.id;
```

You can also store the values in a temporary table, a global temporary table, or a permanent table.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a quick fix is to use excel to generate the case when statements using some smart formulas. I've used that for some huge codes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way if it suits you

```
create table #temp 
(id int, description Varchar(55))
insert into #temp (id)
values ( 1);
insert into #temp (id)
values ( 2);
insert into #temp (id)
values ( 1);
insert into #temp (id)
values ( 3);

update #temp
set description = 'first' where id in (1,2)
;
update #temp
set description = 'Second' where id = 3

select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```